# Android Internal storage

Tags: android, storage, sharedpreferences

I was planing on using the `writeObject` to write my array lists to the internal storage. However, I don't know how to save/restore more than one of them. Like with `SharedPreferences` it makes key/value pairs, but with three `ArrayLists`, how can I save them and then restore them back when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjectOutputStream` uses a `java.io.OutputStream` as argument in its constructor. Since `FileOutputStream` is a derived class of it, you can use it directly. Something like:

```
String FILENAME = "myfile";
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(obj);
oos.close();
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `SharedPreferences` instead, you just need a way to serialize the whole ArrayList (perhaps using a `ObjectOutputStream` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`).

A very easy way to do serialize the array (depending on the complexity of the objects stored) is to create a `JSONArray` to hold the ArrayList values, and use its built-in `toString()` method.

Comment: I understand that, but say I have three objects, how would I write and restore them? I understand I could just call writeObject() three times, but how would I restore them to what I want?

Comment: The easiest way, create three files. Why complicating it? You can do it in one file (e.g., create some xml markup), but I really don't think it's worth in your case.

Comment: I understand that, and I wanted to use three files. But how do I read them back in order.. is it store 1, store 2, store 3.. then read 1, read 2, read 3?

Comment: I honestly don't understand then where are you having problems. Why do you even care about order? You have three files (each one with a file name you chose) and three lists: you just retrieve the data for each list using the same file you used to store it. That's the beauty of object oriented programming: each list does not even know about the other. But to answer directly your question: yes, store 1, 2, 3 and then read 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Ok I just wasnt sure if it was FIFO or LIFO. Sorry, I should have cleared that up before.

Comment: Neither. You'll save them as three independent files. Read them in any order.

Comment: So how do I read them in any order, could you show some code.. as far as I know.. you do writeObject(obj1) writeObject(obj2) writeObject(obj3) then how do you determine which one to read since readObject() doesnt take any parameters is it just.. newObj1 = readObject() newObj2 = readObject() newObj3 = readyObject() or what?

Comment: Then you're using just one file, not three, right? Using three files means using three different ObjectOutputStream instances constructed from three different File instances.

Comment: Right, I want this all in one file. sorry for the typo about, I mean three arrays in one file.

Comment: Then yes, it's FIFO. Verbatim from the java reference (emphasis mine): "The method writeObject is used to write an object to the stream. Any object, including Strings and arrays, is written with writeObject. Multiple objects or primitives can be written to the stream. **The objects must be read back from the corresponding ObjectInputstream with the same types and in the same order as they were written**."